# White screen when createPage with variable in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to create dynamic product page in Gatsby.
Here is what I've edited in file `gatsby-node.js`

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createRedirect } = actions
  const { createPage } = actions

  const {
    data: { products },
  } = await graphql(`
    {
      products: allTestJson {
        edges {
          node {
            brand
            category
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const nodeArray = products.edges.map(edge => edge.node.brand)
  const unique = [...new Set(nodeArray)]
  console.log("UNIQUE")
  console.log(unique)

  unique.forEach((brand) => {
    console.log("BRAND")
    console.log(brand)
    createPage({
      path: `/products/${brand}`,
      component: require.resolve(`./src/pages/contact-us.js`),
    })
  })
}
```

Here I do the console.log and I'm sure the `${node.brand}` returns a value. (One of it is "faro"). However, when I visit /products/faro on the browser, I only see a big white blank page:

[image]

When I change the path to path: "path: `/products/faro`" (just hard code path as products/faro), then the page component renders correctly.

[image]

Is there something wrong with the loop or variable? I'm following this tutorial https://dev.to/notrab/build-static-product-pages-with-gatsby-and-commerce-js-3952

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import { injectIntl, Link, FormattedMessage } from "gatsby-plugin-intl"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import { Background } from "../components/layout/Background"
import { Space } from "../components/layout/Space"
import ShowroomGrid from "../components/organisms/ShowroomGrid"
import ContactForm from "../components/organisms/ContactForm"
import Map from "../components/molecules/Map"

class ContactUs extends Component {
  state = {
    responsiveSize: null,
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({
      responsiveSize: window.innerWidth,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { responsiveSize } = this.state
    return (
      <Layout>
        <SEO
          description="Visit our showrooms in Ho Chi Minh City & Hanoi to admire the timeless masterpieces from Fritz Hansen, Flos, Louis Poulsen, Fontana Arte & Faro."
          title="Contact Us - nanoHome showrooms in HCM & Hanoi"
          keywords={[`luxury`, `lighting`, `furniture`, `showroom`]}
        />
        <Background>
          <MainContainer className="main-container">
            <Space height="64" />
            <H1Tag>nanoHome | Contact Us</H1Tag>
            <SectionMapAndContact responsiveSize={responsiveSize}>
              <GoogleMap>
                <Map />
              </GoogleMap>
              <Contacts>
                <Title>
                  <FormattedMessage id="page-contact-us.section-map-and-contact.title" />
                </Title>
                <Space height="48" />
                <Address>
                  <b>
                    <FormattedMessage id="page-contact-us.section-map-and-contact.office" /> </b> <Space height="16" />
                  <p>
                  <FormattedMessage id="page-contact-us.section-map-and-contact.address" />
                  </p>
                  <Space height="16" />
                  <p>‭+84 90 984 0028</p>
                  <Space height="8" />
                  <p>info@nanohome.vn</p>
                  <Space height="8" />
                  <p>www.nanohome.vn</p>
                </Address>
              </Contacts>
            </SectionMapAndContact>
            <Space height="64" />
            <SectionShowrooms>
              <Title>Our Showrooms</Title>
              <Space height="48" />
              <ShowroomGrid responsiveSize={responsiveSize} />
            </SectionShowrooms>
            <Space height="64" />
            <SectionContactForm responsiveSize={responsiveSize}>
              <Title>Get in Touch</Title>
              <Space height="48" />
              <ContactForm />
            </SectionContactForm>
          </MainContainer>
        </Background>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

const MainContainer = styled.div`
  margin: 0 auto;
`

const SectionMapAndContact = styled.div`
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: ${props =>
    props.responsiveSize > 1024 ? "1fr 1fr" : "1fr"};
  grid-template-rows: ${props =>
    props.responsiveSize < 1024 ? "1fr auto" : "1fr"};
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-gap: ${props => (props.responsiveSize > 1024 ? "4rem" : "2rem")};
`
const GoogleMap = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
`
const Contacts = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 440px;
`
const Title = styled.h2`
  font-size: var(--font-size-larger);
  color: var(--color-primary-blue);
  font-family: "Miller";
`
const Address = styled.div`
  color: var(--color-primary-blue);
  font-size: var(--font-size-large);
  border-left: 2px solid var(--color-primary-blue);
  padding: 0 2rem;
  p {
    font-size: var(--font-size-medium);
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
  }
`
const SectionShowrooms = styled.div`
  padding: 0 2rem;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
`

const SectionContactForm = styled.div`
  width: ${props =>
    (props.responsiveSize > 1024 && "24%") ||
    (props.responsiveSize > 768 && "50%") ||
    (props.responsiveSize > 480 && "80%") ||
    "100%"};
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  min-width: 320px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`

const H1Tag = styled.h1`
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: var(--font-size-smaller);
`

export default ContactUs
```

I also add the debug of unique Array and brand here (sorry it's quite messy as I'm outside)
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to restart gatsby by running `gatsby develop` again?

Comment: Yeah a lot. In fact anytime I edit the gatsby-node I  have to restart it.

Comment: I'm not sure about the detail but, does it work with `gatsby build` and `gatsby serve`?

Comment: @ShinaBR2 `gatsby build` and `gatsbe serve` goes well

Comment: Can you debug a bit more the values of `node.brand`? I assume that the issue comes from there, since if the value it's hardcoded everything works as expected. It's a bit odd to me that a static page (such as /contact-us) has a dynamic creation (it should be a page query), however, it's completely doable.

Comment: Can you debug a bit more the values of `node.brand`? I assume that the issue comes from there, since if the value it's hardcoded everything works as expected. It's a bit odd to me that a static page (such as /contact-us) has a dynamic creation (it should be a page query), however, it's completely doable (summarizing, you are treating a page as a template). Can you also provide a sample of your /contact-us page?

Comment: @FerranBuireu lol I just use the /contact-us as whatever component, I'm only trying to practice with the variable only, I'll replace it with a dynamic ProductPage later. Anw I've add the contact-us component to the questions. I also edit some code to make sure that the brand array contain only unique elements as I suspect if it's like ["Faro", "Faro", "Faro", "Fritz Hansen"], then it may createPage multiple times.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the explanation, I'll sleep better now haha.  Does it output any error on the console when navigating? If it creates the same page multiple times, with the same slug, that might be the issue... Try passing an array of values like `["a", "b", "c"]` to check if it works.

Comment: This: Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received. ?
I suspected the same page multiple times, so I've made 
`const nodeArray = products.edges.map(edge => edge.node.brand)
  const unique = [...new Set(nodeArray)]`
to make sure the array only contains unique element (2 elements)

Comment: I think the runtime.lastError is the result of some extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the "brand data" that I loaded from graphql has some capital letters, and the browser always lowercase text, so it does not match the path in gatsby-node.js. Thank you @harley for spotting this.
Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're *not* getting a 404 page indicates that your page is being created correctly.

Is it possible the page is expecting some sort of props?  In the tutorial you linked, it looks like they are passing an `id` prop.  To pass such props you need to pass a `context` arg to `createPage` (eg. `createPage({ component, path, context: { id })`) ... but the code you provided doesn't have any.

Whatever the problem is, it seems likely that it's in `contact-us.js`, so you'll need to debug it.

Comment: Here I've not passed any props yet. I simply just want to render the contact-us component as i'm still practicing, so no data transferred. I don't think the contact-us.js has any problem as when I replace the `${node.brand}` with "faro" (hard code it), then it rendered correctly. You can see it in the second picture above.

Comment: If that is *literally* true, then you have a typo in `node.brand`, like a space.  I think you really need to add a `console.log(1, node.brand, 2)`,  and look carefully at the results.  But again, something isn't quite adding up, because if you didn't have the path right you'd get a 404 page (try going to `/askjashds` on your site to see what that looks like).

Comment: I figured it out. It's not the spacing but it's the capital letter. As I query the data from a list of products with graphql so the brand is Faro (with the capital F) => the path become /products/Faro. In the browser, Faro will be lowercase to /faro automatically, so it cannot find the path.